# Pass out date from one function to the the next

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a function which gets called by a button, then reaches out to another function (fetchTime) which returns the time, to be alerted in a box from the first button.

```
var today;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    fetchTime();
    alert(today);
  });
});


function fetchTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
  }
  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm;
  }
  var today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
  return(today);
}
```

When I run this I get "undefined" alerted in the box. What am I doing wrong here? Also do I have to define today as a global variable at the top.

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/hc49qes3/2/

Comment: you are not saving return of fetchTime anywhere, change to below
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    let today = fetchTime();
    alert(today);
  });
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fetchTime is returning a value, but you're not storing that value anywhere

The button callback should look like:

```
today = fetchTime();
alert(today);
```

Updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ed3758cm/